# Show/Hide button based on web service response

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a method  that calling a web service (for EndOfDay), and web service returns `"null"` if EndOfDay closed. It's normal but if response is null I need to hide `CloseDay` button that is on another page so I wrote an if statement:

```
using (var response = webrequest.GetResponse())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var responseBuf = reader.ReadToEnd();
    if (responseBuf == null)
    {
        page.CloseDay.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        page.OpenDay.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    String responseJson = Convert.ToString(responseBuf);
    JObject joResponse = JObject.Parse(responseJson);
    dto.Closed = (bool)joResponse["closed"]?.ToObject<bool>();
    return dto;
}
```

Unfortunately it is not working
[image]

It's null but the code does not get into to the if.
My goal is to hide a button if response is null. I did this but there has to be another way. Any idea please?

Comment: Looks like your `responseBuf` is "null" string instead of real null. Check the whole `if` condition in quick watch

Comment: Sho how can I get that string "null" for hide buttons?

Comment: oof, you know that web services can be added as references in VS, and then show up as an object you can instantiate and call methods on like any other, right? what's all this "reading ascii streams from tcp sockets" code?! no-one should do low level stuff like that with webservices; recipe for disaster

Comment: You could just use `if (responseBuf == null || responseBuf == "null")` if you don't want to change your web service. But that's hack-ish

Comment: yeah now worked but I think i made a diffirent mistake. I'm creating an object from my page like ´Batch page;´ but if I call buttons with this object nothing happens and if I call like ´Batch page = new Batch();´ this time it's givin stackoverflow exception. Is there diffirent trick for hide that buttons ? thanks a lot !!